# xquery sort datetime MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Tags: sorting, datetime, format, xquery

I would like to create a xquery function that gets a list of dates in the following format : MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss and returns the min. 
I have created the following but it only works when the dates are in yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss format.

```
 let $dates := <Dates>
                    <date>2012-11-11T10:10:10</date>
                    <date>2012-11-11T10:10:10</date>
                    <date>2012-11-12T10:10:10</date>
                  </Dates>  
 let $DatesStructure := 
     for $date in $dates/date
     order by xs:dateTime($date/text()) descending          
     return <date> {$date/text()}  </date>
 return <Dates> { $DatesStructure } </Dates>
```

I would like to have the same functionality for dates in the following format MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
let $dates := <Dates>
                    <date>11/11/2012 10:10:10</date>
                    <date>11/11/2012 10:10:10</date>
                    <date>11/12/2012 10:10:10</date>
                  </Dates>
 let $DatesStructure :=
     for $date in $dates/date
     order by
     xs:dateTime
        (let $parts := tokenize(substring-before($date, ' '), '/'),
             $y := $parts[3], $m := $parts[1], $d := $parts[2],
             $t := substring-after($date, ' ')
           return
             concat($y,'-',$m,'-',$d, 'T', $t)
         )
     descending
     return <date> {$date/text()}  </date>
 return <Dates> { $DatesStructure } </Dates>
```

**This query produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Dates>
    <date>11/12/2012 10:10:10</date>
    <date>11/11/2012 10:10:10</date>
    <date>11/11/2012 10:10:10</date>
</Dates>
```